# How do I parse a JSON list with different types in Spark?

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this file saved in `/test.json`:

```json
{"changes": [["buy", "0.924000", "34100.21"], ["sell", "0.928000", "101.1"]]}
```

I need to define a schema for it in pyspark and read it in `FAILFAST` mode, but I haven't been able to yet. This is what I have so far and I can't tell why it is wrong:

```py
element = StructType(
    [
        StructField("side", StringType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("price", DecimalType(28, 8), nullable=False),
        StructField("size", DecimalType(28, 8), nullable=False),
    ]
)
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(
            "changes",
            ArrayType(element, containsNull=False),
        )
    ]
)
df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("mode", "FAILFAST").json("/test.json")
df.show(4, truncate=False)
```

The only kind of useful error line in the logs is

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.BadRecordException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse a value for data type
> structside:string,price:decimal(28,8),size:decimal(28,8) (current
> token: START_ARRAY).

Even if I change the "price" and "size" types in `element` to `StringType()`, it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema does not correspond to the data you're trying to read. `changes` is an array of arrays of strings not array so structs.

Try with this instead:

```py
schema = StructType([
    StructField(
        "changes",
        ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(), False), containsNull=False),
    )]
)
df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("mode", "FAILFAST").json("/test.json")

df.show(4, truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------------------------+
#|changes                                             |
#+----------------------------------------------------+
#|[[buy, 0.924000, 34100.21], [sell, 0.928000, 101.1]]|
#+----------------------------------------------------+
```

---

That being said, if you always have sub-arrays of 3 elements and you want to convert them into structs then you can use `transform` function like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "changes",
    F.expr("transform(changes, x -> (x[0] as side, x[1] as price, x[2] as size))")
).show()
```

You can add custom casting inside the transform function to cast `x[1]` and `x[2]` into `DecimalType(28, 8)` if you want.

Comment: I do not have an array of strings, I have a tuple where the first element is a string and the next two are floats. Is there no way to specify this as a schema in Spark?

Comment: @nareto No, you can't. A struct corresponds to json object: `{"side":"buy", "price":0.924000, "size":34100.21}`. But what you have here it is called a json array. You have to read it as arrays then use some transformation as shown above to convert into structs.